Product name - Dynamic request param with elementor PRO
I've created a product template page with Elementor PRO.
Here I putted a button that links to a contact page.
How can I pass the product name dynamically to the contact page url?
Something like www.sitename.com/contacts?productname=**dynamicproductname**
Thanks
M

This can be achieved with the help of given JS Code. In this code we are we are getting Product Name from product title and passing the same with the URL. To add the JS code please navigate to Elementor > Custom CSS & JS and then switch to the JavaScript tab, here we need to add the given code.


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// Replace .elementor-button-class with the CSS class of your Elementor button.
$( '.elementor-button-class' ).each(function() {
    var productName = '';

    // Here we are fetching product name from the page title.
    productName = $(this).closest( '.elementor-template' ).find( '.elementor-heading-title' ).text().trim();

    // Here we are appending the product name to the button URL.
    var currentUrl = $(this).attr( 'href' );
    var newUrl = currentUrl + '?productname=' + encodeURIComponent(productName);
    $(this).attr('href', newUrl);
});

});



